# ^ cause some trouble in regex

Tags: .net, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to match a substring with the regex but the ^ changes the logic as I did not expect.
The regex ...

```
      ^(?!My Words).*$
```

rejects the the sentence which starts with `My Words`. In this case the negative lookahead checks for the whole word.
However, if I drop the `^` then

```
    (?!My Words).*$
```

the regex just returns the `y Words lskjdf` in the sentence containing `My Words lskjdf`. Why the negative lookahead is not treaded as a whole in this case? Why It picks only the `M` for the match? How the `^` and `(?1` is working collectively?

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: I am using the .net regex engine this link I am using to test.. http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html

Comment: What did you expect the `^` to do?

Comment: My expectation from `^` is ok but my expectation from the `(?!` is confusing. I expect this to look for the substring that is not `My Words` but dropping `^` changes the behaviour..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?!My Words).*$
```

`^(?!` means look for the start of a string, or line with the multiline flag, which is not followed by...

This is why any sentence you have starting with "My Words" do not match when using the `^` anchor.

The reason why `y Words` is matched when removing the `^` anchor is that now you are just looking for any point in the string that is not followed by `My Words`, which matches the position after `M`.

Let's look at the string `My Words` and how `(?!My Words).*$` is applied to it.

Keep in mind that `^` is the start of string, even though you did not put it in your regex, the regex engine will still start in that position. I'll simplify a little bit how it works.

First regex engine step:

```
^My Words
|
Regex engine starts here, and looks if the current position onwards
matches (?!My Words), which it does not.
```

Second step:

```
^My Words
 |
 Regex engine evaluates the 'M', and finds that from this position
 onwards also fails to match (?!My Words)
```

Third step:

```
^My Words
  |
  Standing at 'y', it finds that the lookahead now does not match 'My Words'.
  This allows the rest of the pattern '.*$' to be applied, which matches
  from 'y' till end of string.
```

Comment: It doesn't match `M`, it doesn't not match `My Words`. I'll update my answer to explain how the regex engine handles the match.

Comment: Ok.. please explain.. I am waiting ... your last comment again made me confuse.

Comment: It's a good question though, and I can easily understand how this doesn't make any sense at first glance.

Comment: Thanks.. looks very minor issue but confused since last time I asked a question and you answered..

Answer (score 1):

This is because with `^` you are making it **compulsory** to match from the **beginning** of string.

Without `^` it would match **anywhere** in between the string and so it would match `y Words lskjdf`

Comment: HI.. @Anirudh .. Thanks.. I expect the negative lookahead to check for the whole string inside lookahead.. I expect this to work as it is written...

Comment: @SpiralsWhirls As i said with `^` you are explicitly **marking** the start and end of string..Without `^`,regex is free to match anywhere such as `My Words!=y Words!= Words!=Words!=ords!=rds...`